# Does there exist a natural number pair $(a,b)$ such that $a^2b+a+5$ divide $ab^2+a+b$?

Tags: number-theory

I tried that if I can show $\gcd(a^2b+a+5,ab^2+a+b) = 1$, then there is no solution. Am I true?

Any hints /idea?
I can't factorize them out such that each is multiple of each other.

Comment: But, I can't show it. Any hints to show?

Comment: $(5,5)$ is an obvious one of them

Comment: Oh, right. How to ensure it?

Comment: What have you tried?  Looking at examples is always a good way to start.  For the pair $(a,b)=(1,25)$ we have $a^2b+a+5=31$ and $ab^2+a+b=651$ which is divisible by $31$, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $a^2b+a+5$ divides $ab^2+a+b$, we can conclude that it also divides:
$$a(ab^2+a+b)-b(a^2b+a+5)=a^2-5b$$
This means that we must have $a^2-5b=0$ or we must have $|a^2-5b| \geqslant a^2b+a+5$. In the first case, substituting $a=5k$ and $b=5k^2$ gives:
$$(125k^4+5k+5) \mid (125k^5+5k^2+5k)$$
which is obviously true. Next, in the second case, we either have:
$$|a^2| \geqslant |a^2-5b| \implies a^2 \geqslant a^2b+a+5$$
which is impossible, or we have:
$$5b \geqslant |a^2-5b| \geqslant a^2b+a+5 \implies a \leqslant 2$$
If $a=1$, then $b+6$ divides $b^2+b+1$. Performing the same deleting technique gives $b+6 \mid b+37 \implies b+6 \mid 31$ which gives $b=25$.

If $a=2$, then $4b+7$ divides $2b^2+b+2$, and the trick gives $(2,11)$. Can you see that?

Thus, the only solutions are:
$$(a,b)=(5k,5k^2),(1,25),(2,11)$$
for positive integers $k$.

Motivation : We must try to delete the first term in the number divisible by
$ab^2+a+b$ so that we can perform bounding.

Comment: I also found this solution, but I did not prove that it's an unique.

Comment: $(2,11)$ works.

Comment: This is a great explanation. Thanks in advanced. But, I still not understand yet that to delete the first term. What is the first term? that is $a^2b+a+5$ ?

Comment: The $a^2b$ term, it is the biggest

Comment: Similarly, I have left it for you to show that if $4b+7$ divides $2b^2+b+2$, then $b=11$. Try to show this by deleting the quadratic term of $b$, then the linear term of $b$.

Comment: Ah, I see. I must delete the first term of both such that the term $a^2b$ and $ab^2$ deleted, right?

Comment: No, you can't delete the $ab^2$ term in the divisor. That is the one that you have to use to manipulate. Think about it like this. If the divisor has the $ab^2$ term, but if you delete $a^2b$ term in the multiple, you can perform bounding, trying to reason that the divisor is bigger in magnitude, which would give a contradiction

Comment: In your motivation, is true that is $a^2b+a+b$? Not: $a^2b+a+5$ ?

Comment: That is supposed to be $ab^2+a+b$.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thats some little typo. Thanks!

Comment: But, why its not divisible by $a^2b+a+5$?

Comment: in your motivation